# The tag [re-acquisition] should be changed to [reacquisition]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

According to [several](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reacquisition) [online](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reacquisition) [dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reacquisition), the word "reacquisition" does **not** have a hyphen. As such, I stand to change the [re-acquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/re-acquisition) tag to [reacquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reacquisition). (We can keep the same tag description.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made [re-acquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/re-acquisition) a synonym of [reacquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reacquisition) and updated all questions.